# Filter by type in Django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to make a custom queryset where I need to check the type of a foreign key.
The code below works but seems not optimal to me:

```
class BadgeQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def linked_to_convive(self):
        pks_badges_linked_to_convive = [badge.pk for badge in Badge.objects.all()
                                        if badge.owner and
                                        type(badge.owner.profile) == Convive]

        return self.filter(pk__in=pks_badges_linked_to_convive)
```

I browsed Django doc and didn't find something like this:

`Badge.objects.filter(owner__profile__type=Convive)`

- Question 1: Why Django does not provide this kind of tool?
- Question 2: Is there a way to improve my working code, making it simpler?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the model? SQL isn't dynamically typed like Python is, so in general you know the type of a column simply from the data, so it'd help to show why that's not the case in this situation.

Comment: Actually, `profile` is not a model field but a property. I guess that makes my request harder ;)

Comment: In that case, it doesn't even exist until you have Python objects, so it's not possible to create a query based on that property (since the query generates pure SQL). Performing a list comprehension on the Python objects that get created from your query, like you show, seems like the right thing to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't query against properties--the properties are calculated when referenced, and not stored in the database. If there is data in the database that gets you the relevant information, you can query that with the filter() call.

If you show the model definition, though, we might be able to help construct the query.

Comment: Thanks guys. That makes sense. After reading you, it seems my solution is the "less awful" way to do it :)